# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) Tried context refresh already

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have tried various answers to try and get this fixed. I have tried to do a refresh but with no luck.

All my tables are currently empty. I already have @Html.HiddenFor~ in the view

My controller save action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "AdminManager")]
public ActionResult Save(Member member)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new MemberFormViewModel
        {
            Member = member,
            Subjects = _context.Subjects.ToList()
        };
        return View("MemberForm", viewModel);
    }

    if (member.Id == 0)
        _context.Members.Add(member);
    else
    {
        var memberInDb = _context.Members.Single(m => m.Id == member.Id);
        Mapper.Map(memberInDb, member);
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Member");
}
```

Specifically the source error shown is:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

It seems that the code errors when adding a member:

```
_context.Members.Add(member);
```

Below is my table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Members] (
[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]          NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
[DateOfBirth]   DATETIME       NULL,
[Gender]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Email]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[WorkLocation]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Address]       NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
[ContactNumber] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Biography]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[MoreInfo]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[SubjectId]     INT            NOT NULL,
[ReportId]      INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Members] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Members_dbo.Reports_ReportId] FOREIGN KEY ([ReportId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Reports] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Members_dbo.Subjects_SubjectId] FOREIGN KEY ([SubjectId]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Subjects] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SubjectId]
ON [dbo].[Members]([SubjectId] ASC);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ReportId]
ON [dbo].[Members]([ReportId] ASC);
```

Here is my model that was used for the migration:

```
public class Member
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of birth")]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Work Location")]
    public string WorkLocation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    public string Biography { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "More Information")]
    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }

    public Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    public Report Report { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Report")]
    [Display(Name = "Report")]
    public int? ReportId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like your issue is `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` (optimistic concurrency exception), which occasionally originated by more than one `DBContext` instances active at the same time or marking entity as modified when none of the properties have their value(s) "changed". Where is `_context` instance declared?